# Invalid Token Specified on PEAN github cloned project

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, token

I cloned this project from github: 
https://github.com/xkmgt/Angular-7-authentication-postgreSQL.git
Installed all dependencies and run. Unfortunately it displays a blank page and error "Invalid Token Specified" on both 4200 and 3000.

Is there anyone who already tried to fix it?
Cheers

Comment: The question doesn't have enough info. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Share the full error and details.

Comment: I am trying since yesterday but nothing found. Not event " app-component.ts " constructor is also not executing. Except app-module nothing else is executing.